# How to account for velocity term in force component of equations of motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, drag

I am trying to solve for a coefficient of drag that creates a certain situation.

The situation is at a high speed, so the drag at high velocity equation applies:

$$
F_D = \frac{1}{2}\rho v^2 C_d A
$$

If I write down:

$$
\begin{align}
da &= (\frac{d}{dt}\frac{F_D}{m})dt\\
a &= \int(\frac{d}{dt}\frac{F_D}{m})dt\\
v &= v_0 + \int{a}dt\\
x &= x_0 + \int{v}dt\\
\end{align}
$$

Then I am left with a recursion through the chain rule, since $F$ depends on $v$, which depends on $a$, etc.

---

How do I deal with this situation in the context of wind resistance? And I am not sure which tags to add here...

Comment: Why are you differentiating acceleration?

Comment: @probably_someone because force changes with respect to time.

Comment: Yeah, but $F=ma$, so you've got your acceleration right there.

Comment: @probably_someone yes, so a = F/m... and F = ...

Comment: @probably_someone and mass changes with time, in this particular problem.  So I have to differentiate all the way down.  There should be another way to construct this, so I don't get an endless differentiation, but I can't remember how.

Comment: @probably_someone so I've posted the core of the question...

Comment: Do you have an expression for mass as a function of time? There's not much you can say without that.

Comment: @probably_someone yeah, it's m= m_o - (constant)*t (on the cellphone at the moment)

Comment: I think this is the right equation
$m\,\frac{dv}{dt}=1/2\rho\,v^2\,C_d\,A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $k=\rho C_D A/2$, and letting $m=m_0 - bt$ for constant $b$, we have

$a=\frac {dv}{dt}=\frac {kv^2}{m_0-bt}$.

This is a first-order ODE in $v$, with solution

$v=\frac {b}{k\log (m_0-bt)-C}$,

where $C$ satisfies $v(0)=v_0$.

Comment: cleaned up my comments here

Comment: What is funny is that I don’t remember why I was confused—was probably thinking in terms of code.  Didn’t mean to come off the way i did.

Comment: @bordeo No problem - fighting the backfire effect is always difficult.